# Is it okay for a Righteous Gentile to wear a Star of David around the neck?

Tags: star-of-david

I am not a Jew at all. I am a Gentile that goes to the Synagogue and believes in Hashem and practices prayers that do not involve heritage, as that would be lying to him. I follow the Seven Noahide Laws and study the Tanach. Would it be offensive to the Jewish people to wear a Star of David around the neck?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for bringing your question here. Fortunately, it's been answered already; please see the other question linked to above.

Comment: Buddy, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the question! Since it was already answered before, it got closed. But I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: no, it would not be offensive. It's just a cultural symbol and has no connection to Judaism.

Comment: Hey, me and my wife just bought a star of david for a gentile, so I don't think it is offensive. :)